# C# Client Request To Get A Encrypted Image From Php Script

Tags: c#, php, ssl, encryption

C# Client Sends Web request To a PHP Script To get A Image
,PHP Needs To Send The Image In encrypted Format To The Client

Encryption Used - Asymmetric (Public Key And Private Key)

client Creates Key Pair ,Public key Which Is Uploaded To Server
PHP Script Uses That Public Key To Encrypt The Image And
Send To Client, Client Decrypt The Image With Its Private Key

but I Cant Get The PHP Script Work(key parameter is not a valid public key Error)

C#

```
private void Submitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://localhost/req.php";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"test.jpg");
    }
```

PHP

```
<?Php
include('phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php');
$data=file_get_contents("private.png");
$key= file_get_contents('KeyBag\PBkey');
openssl_public_encrypt($data,$output,$key);
    $mm_type="application/octet-stream";
    header("hst: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
    header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($output)) );
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($output).'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
    readfile($output); 
    exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: Step #1, ignore the C# and uploading parts for now, get it working in just PHP with baked in values. There are several key formats, binary and text, so make sure you know what to expect and test for.

Comment: Given the include, I guess you are trying to encrypt with a SSH public key, while you need a PKCS#1 or X.509 formatted public key. However, the PHP documentation is such a frickin mess that I cannot establish which.

Comment: @ Maarten Bodewes ...that is the real reason why i am here